# Access key, value in a JSON object within an array with SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm a bit stuck with accessing a value in an object contained in a `JSON` array. I've tried `UNNEST()` to no avail. Adding `OFFSET` or `ORDINAL` did not work. It threw `Array index 0 is out of bounds (overflow)`

Here is the query:

```
SELECT d.dealid, associations.associatedvids FROM hs.deals as d 
WHERE associations.associatedvids is not null
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Your first id is not null.  Try != '' in addition to the is not null

Comment: That was it! Thanks!

Comment: Can you think of any WHERE condition that will work with []. It seems that != '' still returns rows with [].

`No matching signature for operator != for argument types: STRUCT<value INT64>, STRING. Supported signatures: ANY != ANY at [2:7]`

IS NOT NULL does return some rows with [].

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that some rows included an empty array []. I've added WHERE condition to remove such rows:

```
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(d.associations.associatedvids) >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier alternative: `SAFE`

```sql
SELECT [][OFFSET(0)]
# Array index 0 is out of bounds (overflow)


SELECT [][SAFE_OFFSET(0)]
# null
```